# What operator do I need to overload?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload the "receiver" operator so I can do this: `someClass >> myClass`.

...where myClass is the class which I need to overload the operator for.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mysticial pointed out, you need to overload `operator>>` to do this.

That overload can **not** be a member of `myClass` though. It must be either a member of `someClass`, or else a global overload.

```
class someClass { 
// ...
    someClass &operator>>(myClass &);
};
```

or:

```
someClass &operator>>(someClass &, myClass &);
```

If the operator doesn't/can't change the state of the `someClass` object, you might want to pass the first parameter by const reference (in which case you'd also return a const reference).

Of course, returning a `someClass` isn't really required, but it's the normally accepted practice for this kind of operator (it allows chaining the operators for something like `a >> b >> c;`)

Comment: So how do I edit myClass so it is "able to receive" what someClass "sends it". I can't edit someClass.

Comment: As shown above, if you have to leave `someClass` alone, then you need to make your overload global (and often a friend of `myClass`). As Mehrdad pointed out, if you're using namespaces, chances are that you'll need ADL for it to be found (you'd want to put it in the same namespace as `myClass`).

Answer (score 2):

`>>` *is* the operator. You want to overload `operator>>`. The signature will look like this:

```
someClass& operator>>(someClass&, myClass&);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)... I haven't used it myself very often, but you need to overload `operator >>` with ADL (see the link).